# Cassandra compaction failed due to OutOfMemoryError: null

Tags: cassandra

During the weekly compaction, this one failed on this 1 node setup
I found 2 errors related but I'm not sure how to check what was the cause and how to fix it (I'm a beginner with Cassandra)

First error:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:3928] 2020-11-11 03:48:35,823 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:3928,1,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.<init>(SafeMemory.java:32) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.copy(SafeMemory.java:72) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Writer.addOffset(CompressionMetadata.java:337) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.flushData(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:125) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.doFlush(SequentialWriter.java:213) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:151) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.writeValue(AbstractType.java:394) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringPrefix$Serializer.serializeValuesWithoutSize(ClusteringPrefix.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Clustering$Serializer.serialize(Clustering.java:131) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.add(ColumnIndex.java:198) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.buildRowIndex(ColumnIndex.java:94) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:161) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.SplittingSizeTieredCompactionWriter.realAppend(SplittingSizeTieredCompactionWriter.java:91) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.append(CompactionAwareWriter.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:60) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.runMayThrow(CompactionManager.java:678) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Second one:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:3928] 2020-11-11 03:48:36,323 JVMStabilityInspector.java:140 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.<init>(SafeMemory.java:32) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.copy(SafeMemory.java:72) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Writer.addOffset(CompressionMetadata.java:337) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.flushData(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:125) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.doFlush(SequentialWriter.java:213) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:151) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.writeValue(AbstractType.java:394) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringPrefix$Serializer.serializeValuesWithoutSize(ClusteringPrefix.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Clustering$Serializer.serialize(Clustering.java:131) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.add(ColumnIndex.java:198) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.buildRowIndex(ColumnIndex.java:94) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:161) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.SplittingSizeTieredCompactionWriter.realAppend(SplittingSizeTieredCompactionWriter.java:91) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.append(CompactionAwareWriter.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:60) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.runMayThrow(CompactionManager.java:678) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks in advance

---

adding more info:

C:\Program Files\Cassandra\bin>nodetool info
ID                     : ac6360e3-b046-430d-ac0b-9bbbf97c3adb
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 128.54 GiB
Generation No          : 1605108336
Uptime (seconds)       : 112223
Heap Memory (MB)       : 2698.26 / 7987.25
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 58.62
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 10
Key Cache              : entries 45228, size 13.87 MiB, capacity 100 MiB, 456542 hits, 504019 requests, 0.906 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 7680, size 480 MiB, capacity 480 MiB, 650394 misses, 1218675 requests, 0.466 recent hit rate, 1220.023 microseconds miss latency
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)

Comment: We don't have much information to go on - some more information about the heap size, cassandra version, maximum partition size on the table being compacted etc

Comment: Version looks like 3.7 which is relatively out of date, so more information about version and why you are on an older out of date version would be useful.

Comment: Also 1.8.0_91 is an old patch level of Java 8.  Try updating to the newest patch level, and provide your JVM settings.  My guess, is that your heap sizing is too small.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your comments I just added more details to the question, the DB is running on a windows server